# About matrix exponentials

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices

Suppose $M$ is a $n$-dimensional matrix and $v$ and $w$ are two vectors in $n-$dimensions.  I want to be able to say that $\vert \langle e^{-M \cdot t} v, w \rangle \vert$ or $e^{-M \cdot t} v$ itself, is function  monotonically decreasing to $0$ with $t$.

- What is a necessary and/or sufficient condition for the above conclusion to hold?
- Likewise, is $M$ being a positive definite matrix enough?

Comment: In general, $M$ is WLOG a direct sum of Jordan blocks. If you write out the condition that $\langle e^{-Mt}v,w\rangle$ and its derivative are positive, you get a pair of inequalities involving polynomial-combinations of exponentials. (It gets even trickier if there are complex eigenvalues, I guess.)

Comment: Sure. But is $M$ being a real P.D matrix enough to guarantee what I want?

Comment: I was going to write an answer but realized that $M$ positive definite only guarantees a decreasing function, not necessarily *monotonically* so. Is that condition necessary?

Comment: Please write in your answer. As long as its decreasing to $0$, I guess its reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

For $e^{-Mt}v$ to diminish to zero, what is required is that $v\in E^+(M)$, the subspace generated by eigenspaces of eigenvalues having strictly positive real part. If $M$ is positive definite self-adjoint, then $E^+(M)$ is the whole vector space.

If $v\in E^+(M)$, then $v=\sum_i\alpha_ie_i$ with $Me_i=\lambda_ie_i$, $\mathrm{Re}(\lambda_i)>0$. $$e^{-Mt}v=\sum_i\alpha_ie^{-\mathrm{Re}(\lambda_i)t}e^{\mathrm{i Im}(\lambda_i)t}e_i\to0$$ This is not true when $v$ has a component in $E^0(M)$ or $E^-(M)$.

For $\langle w,e^{-Mt}v\rangle$ to go to zero, the condition can be relaxed to $$w\in(E^0(M)+E^-(M))^\perp$$ because then any component of $v$ in those spaces will be dotted to zero.